# Insert date and tag name into LaTeX source files with git

Tags: git, latex

I'm using git for writing some LaTeX packages. To be able to make use of LaTeX release features, a string of the following format needs to be included in each package:

```
\ProvidesPackage{MyPackageName}[yyyy/mm/dd VersionNumber SomeText]
```

I often forget to update the date and version number before I upload the files to CTAN and was wondering if git can be used to automate this.

I am looking for a method to:

1. automatically insert the current date into the source code upon every commit for only the files changed in this commit
2. automatically insert the current date and version number into all files when I tag a version (the tag name is the same as the version number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## To automatically do things with `git`, use hooks

You want to do `\thing{}` with every git commit? That's what a [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) is for. For example, the `post-commit` hook:

> After the entire commit process is completed, the post-commit hook runs. It doesn’t take any parameters, but you can easily get the last commit by running `git log -1 HEAD`. Generally, this script is used for notification or something similar.

*from  the GIT SCM website / manual*

### Adding a date with every `git commit`

This is the straightforward part. You could use this hook to achieve the first part of your two goals quite simply:

1. use `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD` to get the files changed in the current revision (see [this explanation on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142))
2. iterate over those files in the language of your choice and use the tool of your choice to insert the date, for example with `sed` or `awk`

If you do this locally, it will leave you with changed unstaged files on your working copy; **ie `git status` will show changed files**. You may want to avoid that by using an additional repo as below.

### Adding a version with each `git tag`

This is slightly trickier.

You could work around the fact that `git tag` does not trigger any hooks by using an intermediate git repo - either locally or remote - and `git push` to that repo each time you tag. You could then use a `post-update` hook on that server to rewrite based on the latest tag.

For example:

1. Get the latest tag / version name: `git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)`
2. Format the files using `sed` (or `awk` or whichever tool you choose)
3. Upload to CTAN from that directory

#### Can't I do this with another hook?

It *is* possible to detect if a ref has a tag by using `git describe`, for example:

```bsh
# In a working git repo
$ git tag -a "test1" -m "test tag"
$ git describe --exact-match HEAD
test1
$ git describe --exact-match HEAD^1
fatal: no tag exactly matches 'f8a1d888151809ccfbb3460bbcf310541967e292'
128
```

However, using `git tag` will not trigger a `commit` hook.

Comment: Fantastic answer with very good explanation! Thanks a lot!